# Java Sudoku correct number input

Tags: java, sudoku

Here's the code to my sudoku game. It will accept input for the blank cells but for some reason it is not changing color to indicate whether the input is right or wrong. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;     
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.*;     


public class Sudoku extends JFrame 
{
  long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  public static final int gridDim = 9;//board size
  public static final int subGridDim = 3; //sub grid size
  public static final int cellSize = 60;
  public static final int width  = 630;
  public static final int height = 630;
  public static final Color emptyCell= Color.blue;
  public static final Color correct = new Color(0, 255, 0);
  public static final Color incorrect = Color.RED;
  public static final Color backgroundColor = new Color(240, 240, 240); 
  public static final Color backgroundColorColor = Color.BLACK;
  public static final Font fontColor = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20);

  private JTextField[][] tfCells = new JTextField[9][9];

  String x;
  int y;
  private int[][] puzzle = {{5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2},
            {6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8},
            {1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7},
            {8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3},
            {4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1},
            {7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6},
            {9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4},
            {2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5},
            {3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9}};

  private boolean[][] masks = {{true, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false},
            {false, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, true},
            {true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
            {true, false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false},
            {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
            {false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false},
            {true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
            {false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false},
            {true, false, true, false, false, true, false, false, false}};

  public Sudoku() 
  {
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,9));
    InputListener listener = new InputListener();

    for (int row = 0; row < gridDim; ++row) //build 9x9 text fields
    {
      for (int col = 0; col < gridDim; ++col) 
      {
        tfCells[row][col] = new JTextField(); 
        cp.add(tfCells[row][col]);
        if (masks[row][col]) //if empty cell
        {
          tfCells[row][col].setText("");
          tfCells[row][col].setEditable(true);
          tfCells[row][col].setBackground(correct);
          tfCells[row][col].addActionListener(listener);  
        } 
        else //if cell is filled
        {
          tfCells[row][col].setText(puzzle[row][col] + "");
          tfCells[row][col].setEditable(false);
          tfCells[row][col].setBackground(backgroundColorColor);
          tfCells[row][col].setForeground(backgroundColor);
        }

        tfCells[row][col].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER); // fix cells
        tfCells[row][col].setFont(fontColor);
      }
    }
    cp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height)); //set window size
    pack();

    setTitle("Sudoku");
    setVisible(true);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Sudoku app = new Sudoku();
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
  private class InputListener implements ActionListener 
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
      int rowSelected = -1; //determines which row/column is being looked at
      int colSelected = -1;
      JTextField source = (JTextField)e.getSource();
      boolean found = false; 
      for (int row = 0; row < gridDim && !found; ++row)// Scan fields for all rows and columns +
                                                            //match with the source object
      {
        for (int col = 0; col < gridDim && !found; ++col) 
        {
          if (tfCells[row][col] == source)
          {
            rowSelected = row;
            colSelected = col;
            found = true;  // break the inner/outer loops
          }
        }
      }
      x = tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].getText(); //get input
      y = Integer.parseInt(x);
      if(y==puzzle[rowSelected][colSelected])
      {
        tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setBackground(Color.green);
      }
      else
        tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setBackground(Color.red);

      if(masks[rowSelected][colSelected])//if all answers are correct
      {
        long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(endtime - starttime); // time in seconds
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Finished in: " + timeSeconds);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a `NumberFormatException` when you attempt the `y = Integer.parseInt(x);`

To fix this add a `catch` that will set the box red in your `actionPerformed`.

```
x = tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].getText(); //get input
try {
    y = Integer.parseInt(x);
    System.out.println(y);
    if(y==puzzle[rowSelected][colSelected]) {
         tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setBackground(Color.green);
    } else {
         tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    if(masks[rowSelected][colSelected]) { //if all answers are correct
         long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         long timeSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(endtime - starttime); // time in seconds
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Finished in: " + timeSeconds);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException exc){
    tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setBackground(Color.red);
}
```

Comment: My pop up box is only supposed to come up if the puzzle is fully completed and correct. Instead it is coming up after every input, whether correct or not. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: when you do your check on the `masks[rowSelected][colSelected]` at the end of your `actionPerformed` have it check all the rows and cols for a `true`.  If none are `true` than the game is over and display the popup.  Currently you are checking if the current mask selected is true.

Comment: Also, you never set your mask to `false` after a user gets the number right.